# SQL Query for Employee Table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I need help to write SQL to print the following

table 1 : Emp_Master

```
Emp_ID   FirstName
------------------------------
1            John
2            Mark
3            Steve
```

table 2 : Emp_Transaction

```
Trans ID    Emp_ID    Payment_Date  Paid_status
---------------------------------------------------------
1               1             01/07/13         True
2               1             01/15/13         False
3               1             01/21/13         False
4               2             01/07/13         False
5               2             01/15/13         False
6               2             01/21/13         False
7               3             01/07/13         True
8               3             01/15/13         True
9               3             01/21/13         False
```

Result should print like this ( oldest unpaid date)

```
Emp_ID   FirstName            Payment_Date        Paid_Status
--------------------------------------------------------------
1             John                  01/15/13           False
2             Mark                  01/07/13           False
3             steve                 01/21/13           Fals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT e.Emp_ID, e.FirstName, min(Payment_Date), et.Paid_Status 
FROM Emp_Master e, Emp_Transaction et
WHERE e.Emp_ID = et.Emp_ID AND et.Paid_Status= 'False' 
GROUP BY  e.Emp_ID, e.FirstName, et.Paid_Status
```

Comment: You should be using explicit join notation. This is also missing the paid_status

Comment: How is it missing the paid_status? I didnt got you.

Comment: it's not in the SELECT list?

Comment: Perfect, Thank You so much for your help, I was pulling my hair for two hours.

Answer (score 2):

I overly complicated my first answer. This is all you need.

```
SELECT Emp_Master.Emp_ID Emp_ID, FirstName, MIN(Payment_Date) Payment_Date,  Paid_Status
FROM Emp_Master
 INNER JOIN  Emp_Transaction ON Emp_Master.Emp_ID = Emp_Transaction.Emp_ID
WHERE Paid_Status = 'false'
GROUP BY Emp_Master.Emp_ID, FirstName, Paid_Status
```

Comment: MIN(Payment_Date) with Status false, isn't it?

Comment: @SenJacob Correct - fixed my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  select model1.Emp_ID  ,
         model1.FirstName ,
         min(model2.Payment_Date) ,
         model2.Paid_Status
         from Emp_Master model1 ,Emp_Transaction model2 
         where model1.Emp_ID  =  model2.Emp_ID GROUP BY  model1.Emp_ID, model2.FirstName;
```

Comment: you're missing a join in your GROUP BY. You should also be using explicit join notation

Answer (score -1):

You may use `Join` for this.

> Select e.Emp_ID, e.FirstName,min(t.Payment_Date) ,
>     t.Paid_status from Emp_Master e,
>   Emp_Transaction t where e.Emp_ID = t.Emp_ID and t.Paid_Status = 'false';

Comment: this doesn't get the minimum payment date